# Thread running the second time gives error

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

I'm using threads in Windows to connect a plug-in made in c++ to a python script. The thread is to be called many times in the duration of the session

**Question:**

When the worker thread that calls the python script is called a second time this happens:

->The .exe program crashes with code:
*"Runtime Error!
Program: xxx.exe.
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information"*

->In Visual studio it says: *"First-chance exception at 0x7735C41F in xxx.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CInvalidArgException at memory location 0x06A9F840.*
*If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."*

leading me to these lines of `mlock.c` :

```
void __cdecl _unlock (
    int locknum
    )
{
    /*
     * leave the critical section.
     */
    LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Where am i not handling an exception properly?

One thing i noticed from the debugging it that `_endthread()` on the last line is never reached and i have no idea why. Is this the source of the problem?

**Code:**

Here's the code for the worker thread:

```
void py_embed (void*data){

char *argv[4]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign","MAH543"};
int argc=4;

ofstream textfile3;
textfile3.open("FP_python_embed.txt");

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
PyThreadState *mainThreadState,*myThreadState,*tempState;
PyInterpreterState *mainInterpreterState;

//To inform the interpreter about paths to Python run-time libraries
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);

// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();

// Initialize thread support
PyEval_InitThreads();

// Save a pointer to the main PyThreadState object
mainThreadState = PyThreadState_Get();

// Get a reference to the PyInterpreterState
mainInterpreterState = mainThreadState->interp;

// Create a thread state object for this thread
myThreadState = PyThreadState_New(mainInterpreterState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Acquire global lock
PyEval_AcquireLock();

// Swap in my thread state
tempState = PyThreadState_Swap(myThreadState);

// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);

// Load the module object
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, argv[2]);

//Do the Python things
PyObject *pArgs2, *pValue2;
pArgs2=Py_BuildValue("(s)",argv[3]);
pValue2 = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs2);
textfile3<<PyInt_AsLong(pValue2)<<endl<<" worked1";
textfile3.close();

// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// Swap out the current thread
PyThreadState_Swap(tempState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Clean up thread state
PyThreadState_Clear(myThreadState);
PyThreadState_Delete(myThreadState);

// Finish the Python Interpreter
Py_Finalize();

_endthread();
};
```

And what i do to call it from the main thread(that closes before the worker thread is finished):

```
handle=(HANDLE) _beginthread(py_embed,0,NULL);
```

***Note: Question 2 related to this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414271/how-to-use-closed-handle-in-a-worker-thread).***

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: you think i should divide this question in two?

Comment: You have already divided it into two yourself. Just post the two separately, stand-alone.

Comment: Im also facing the problem. Calling the function with Py_Initialize the second time gives and error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203219/calling-the-function-containing-py-initialize-second-time-gives-error-segmen 

can you tell me the solution

Comment: I can't, as this was so many years ago and I don't remember. Sorry @AreebMuzaffar