# How to use closed handle in a worker thread

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I'm using threads in Windows to connect a plug-in made in c++ to a python script. The thread is to be called many times in the duration of the session

**Question:**

If I pass the `ArgList` in the `_beginthread` the error *"Unhandled exception at 0x1E114A68 (python27.dll) in xxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFE."* is raised and I think it's because of this i read in [CreatingThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of Windows Dev Center:

*" Note that if you were to close the handle to a worker thread before it terminated, this does not terminate the worker thread. However, the handle will be unavailable for use in subsequent function calls."*

Am I right about the origin of this error? How do I work past this?

**Code:**

I called `_beginthread` with `NULL` as the `ArgList` and defined the `ArgList` inside the worker thread just for getting the thread to work. Here's the code for the worker thread:

Note: I noticed while debugging that `_endthread()` is not reached. Is that normal?

```
void py_embed (void*data){

char *argv[4]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign","MAH543"};
int argc=4;

ofstream textfile3;
textfile3.open("FP_python_embed.txt");

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
PyThreadState *mainThreadState,*myThreadState,*tempState;
PyInterpreterState *mainInterpreterState;

//To inform the interpreter about paths to Python run-time libraries
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);

// Initialize the Python Interpreter
Py_Initialize();

// Initialize thread support
PyEval_InitThreads();

// Save a pointer to the main PyThreadState object
mainThreadState = PyThreadState_Get();

// Get a reference to the PyInterpreterState
mainInterpreterState = mainThreadState->interp;

// Create a thread state object for this thread
myThreadState = PyThreadState_New(mainInterpreterState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Acquire global lock
PyEval_AcquireLock();

// Swap in my thread state
tempState = PyThreadState_Swap(myThreadState);

// Build the name object
pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);

// Load the module object
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

// pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, argv[2]);

//Do the Python things
PyObject *pArgs2, *pValue2;
pArgs2=Py_BuildValue("(s)",argv[3]);
pValue2 = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs2);
textfile3<<PyInt_AsLong(pValue2)<<endl<<" worked1";
textfile3.close();

// Clean up
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// Swap out the current thread
PyThreadState_Swap(tempState);

// Release global lock
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

// Clean up thread state
PyThreadState_Clear(myThreadState);
PyThreadState_Delete(myThreadState);

// Finish the Python Interpreter
Py_Finalize();

_endthread();
};
```

And what I do to call it from the main thread(that closes before the worker thread is finished):

```
handle=(HANDLE) _beginthread(py_embed,0,NULL);
```

***NOTE:Question 1 related to this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413706/thread-running-the-second-time-gives-error)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i finally found the problem. Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem i did

I still don't fully understand how this works but i basically need to dynamically allocate memory on the heap using `new` in c++ (and `malloc` in c). More information about this [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)

In my case I will need to do something like this:

```
#define NUM_ARGUMENTS 4
typedef struct{
int argc;
char *argv[NUM_ARGUMENTS];
}SENDTOPY;
```

And then on the main thread:

```
SENDTOPY *cmd;

char *argv[4]={"PythonPlugIn2","bridge","test_callsign","MAH543"};
int i;

cmd= new SENDTOPY();
cmd->argc=4;
for( i = 0; i < NUM_ARGUMENTS; i++ )
{cmd->argv[i] = argv[i];}

handle=(HANDLE) _beginthread(py_embed,0,(void*)cmd);
```

I still need to understand this better, and also learn how to deallocate at the end with `delete` but I'm in the right way.

Note: I still need help on the [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413706/thread-running-the-second-time-gives-error) related to this, so please have a look at it.

Comment: the reason is that in your old code, `cmd` exists only within the scope of your if statement. So once that if statement ends, that memory is reclaimed - but since you've given its memory address to `handle`, you get errors when `handle` attempts to do something with it.

Comment: if you don't want do the manual memory management like you've done there, you can also simply raise the scope of `cmd` to be the same as `handle`, so that data is guaranteed to exist when `handle` needs it.

Comment: also, if you want a hybrid of those two solutions, you can use a `scoped_ptr`, which you can use automatically the handle the destruction of a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: I've already gone with manually but, for the sake of knowledge, how do I raise a scope?

Comment: Scope is just the depth at which a variable exists in your program. If you have something like `if(condition){ SENDTOPY *cmd; ... }`, `*cmd` is gone after that if statement ends. If you do `SENDTOPY *cmd; if(condtion) { ... }`, `*cmd` will exist until that larger scope ends.